# Dynamic variable name for Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is there another way to make this possible?

```
(Entity1*)[entity1attributes objectAtIndex:i] = [[groupOfAlphabetObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:idx];
```

where entity1attributes is an array containing strings like "e.abc1", "e.def1", etc.

Prior to this line, I have declared and initialized Entity1 by

```
Entity1 *e = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity1" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I need this because I run through many arrays and add them accordingly one string by one string to attributes in Entity1.

EDIT:

It is not only adding strings, I have also to set up one attribute to another Entity's relating attribute. So it is not possible to do this in "one's line adding" through NSDictionary or NSArray...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using KVC, specifically `setValue:forKeyPath:` which will allow you to navigate to properties on the entity and other entities in its relationships by configuration data.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have checked it out earlier!